# (1045, "Access denied for user 'Umair07'@'10.0.0.100' (using password: YES)")?

Tags: python, mysql, pythonanywhere

```
import pymysql
try:
    conn = pymysql.connect(host='pythonanywherehost', user='user', passwd='password', database='db_name')

except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
```

But when i run this file on Console provided by the PythonAnywhere Domain 
it gives me an error below like this

```
(1045, "Access denied for user 'Umair07'@'10.0.0.100' (using password: YES)")
```

i have entered the correct login credentials for the database username and password but it gives me a the same error and i don't know what i m doing wrong

Any Help would be Appreciated and thanks in Advance

Comment: The login might only be allowed from localhost - check the create user statement or grant statement used as that will tell you which hosts the user is allowed to connect from.

Comment: okay let me try

Comment: i can't create any user and even can't grant privileges to the user it give me an error

Comment: Then you need to check with the service provider.

Comment: There are 4 pieces of information that need to be correct to log in to your database: the host, the username, the database name and the password. You've obscured all of them. Contact PythonAnywhere support and we'll be able to help you.